# Load javascript function that draws html elements after publish web project in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get some javascript code working on my MVC4 project after I publish, this is the function that is bothering me, because it shows a 500 (Internal Server Error) on webconsole
"POST http://10.10.10.10:8080/MyProject/Home/WebMedia 500 (Internal Server Error)jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.9.1.js:8526jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.9.1.js:7978reloadDataTable1 @ Home:315
Home:361 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "

status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}"

Does work in local but after publishing it, won't load it.
I can't seem to find a fix for it, any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.
HTML & JAVASCRIPT:

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" id="Table1">
     <!-- Show table with information... it's loaded through javascript -->
</div>

$(function () 
{
    reloadDataTable1();

    function reloadDataTable1() 
    {
            setTimeout(reloadDataTable1, 25000);
            console.log("asking data...");

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '@Url.Action("WebMedia")',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    console.log("I have data!");
                    console.log(data);

                    console.log("Now I'm drawing the table");

                    var tr = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        tr += "<tr>";

                        tr += "<td>" + data[i].Name + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + data[i].response + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + data[i].hour + "</td>";

                        tr += "</tr>";
                    }

                    var Table_Content = "";
                    Table_Content += "<table id='Table1-content'>";

                    Table_Content += "<tr><td colspan='3'>Response time per hour</td></tr>";

                    Table_Content += "<tr>";
                    Table_Content += "<td style='background-color:#ECE6E1; text-align:center'><b>Webservice</b></td>";
                    Table_Content += "<td style='background-color:#ECE6E1; text-align:center'><b>ResponseTime)</b></td>";
                    Table_Content += "<td style='background-color:#ECE6E1; text-align:center'><b>Hour</b></td>";
                    Table_Content += "</tr>";

                    console.log(tr);

                    Table_Content += tr;

                    Table_Content += "</table>";

                    $("#Table1").html(Table_Content);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }    
});
```

```
    Method define in Home Controller: 

    public JsonResult WebMedia()
                {
                    mydataservice objMD = new mydataservice();
                    var ws = objMD.webMedia();
                    return Json(ws, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
    I obtein values like this from my sql query:
    response  hour  name
    0,01       10   Name1          
    0,02       10   Name2             
    21,9       10   Name3       
    0,10       10   Name4               
    0,55       10   Name5
```

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` generally means your controller method is throwing an exception. You need to show the controller

Comment: In my controller I have a method that returns a json object, from an sql query.

Comment: after publish your mydataservice seems does not available, check it

Comment: How can I check this?